# seekbar using first 0.12 and 0.13 combination adding the value

Tags: java, android, eclipse

seekbar using volume increment and decrement for 0.12 and 0.13 combination like 0.12,0.25,0.37,0.50,0.62,0.75,0.87 but i getting values like this 0.12,0.25,0.38,0.50,0.62,0.75,0.88 .Please suggest me how can i clear the issues.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b1;
SeekBar sk1;
double point=0.12;
double value=0.00;
int previous=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sk1=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    sk1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int p = progress;
            double f = progress;
            double x = Double.parseDouble(b1.getText().toString());             
            if (point == 0.12)
            {
                if (previous > p) 
                {
                    if (x == -20.00 )
                    {

                    } 
                    else {
                        float a = (float) (0.25 / 2 * 100) / 100;
                        f = value - a;
                        b1.setText(""+ String.format("%.2f",(f)));
                        value=f;
                    }
                }
                else if (previous < p)
                {
                    if (x == 20.00) 
                    {
                    }
                    else {
                        float a = (float) (0.25   / 2 * 100) / 100;
                        f = value + a;
                        b1.setText(""+ String.format("%.2f",(f)));
                        value=f;
                    }
                }                   
            }
            previous = progress;
        }
    });
}
```